# Is there a way to create hash(sha256) for images in Yocto's swupdate layer?

Tags: yocto, sha256, software-update, rsa-sha256

My objective is,

1. To create `sha256` for all the required files(which go into `.swu`)
2. To Sign `sw-description` file with `RSA` algorithm.

My `.swu` consists:

- kernel Image - `bzImage`
- rootfile system - `panther2-usb-panther2.ext4`
- software description file - `sw-description`
- post install script - `postinstall_swu.sh`

I have created a script which generates `sha256` and signs `sw-description`.
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGES="bzImage panther2-usb-panther2.ext4"
FILES="sw-description sw-description.sig postinstall_swu.sh $IMAGES"
echo "Executing swu signing script..."

cp ../sw-description .
cp ../postinstall_swu.sh .
cp ../../../../../deploy/images/panther2/bzImage .
cp ../../../../../deploy/images/panther2/panther2-usb-panther2.ext4 .

read -d ' ' SHA_ROOTFS < <(sha256sum panther2-usb-panther2.ext4)
read -d ' ' SHA_BZIMAGE < <(sha256sum bzImage)
read -d ' ' SHA_POSTINSTALL < <(sha256sum postinstall_swu.sh)

sed -i ':a;N;$!ba; s/sha256 = "[0-9A-Za-z]*"/sha256 = '"\"${SHA_ROOTFS}"\"'/1' sw-description
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba; s/sha256 = "[0-9A-Za-z]*"/sha256 = '"\"${SHA_BZIMAGE}"\"'/2' sw-description
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba; s/sha256 = "[0-9A-Za-z]*"/sha256 = '"\"${SHA_POSTINSTALL}"\"'/3' sw-description

openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ../priv.pem -passin file:../passphrase sw-description > sw-description.sig

for i in $FILES;do
        echo $i;done | cpio -ov -H crc >  panther2-swu-$USER-devbuild.swu

cp panther2-swu-$USER-devbuild.swu ../../../../../deploy/images/panther2
```

> Is above approach better?

Is there a way to ask yocto/swupdate layer to generate `sha256` for all above files(except `sw-description`) and add these generated `sha256` into sw-description file?

I can sign `sw-description` by defining `SWUPDATE_SIGNING` and`SWUPDATE_PRIVATE_KEY` variables in my recipe file but

> how to generate `sha256`?

Comment: Again do no reinvent the wheel, meta-swupdate already does it very well. If you want to do it yourself, you can use `bb.utils.sha256_file` python function

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I do to enable `sha256` generation in meta-swupdate since I couldn't find it anywhere. Any configuration or environment variable which needs to be set

Comment: I added a comment in your previous post with information about it.

Comment: I had gone through those links and not found anything on `sha256` which made me to post this question

Comment: Maybe [this page](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/building-with-yocto.html) explains it better. You just have to add `sha256 = "@panther2-usb-panther2.ext4";` in `sw-description` to autogenerate sha256, then you need to add `SWUPDATE_SIGNING SWUPDATE_IMAGES SWUPDATE_IMAGES_FSTYPES` variables in recipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nayfe, it worked, so happy, made my day !!!! You could post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

meta-swupdate Yocto layer takes care of signed images.

Swupdate image recipe should contain for example:

```
SWUPDATE_SIGNING = "RSA" 
SWUPDATE_PRIVATE_KEY = "/path/to/key"
```

Then, sha256 is automatically computed in `sw-description file` with following syntax:

```
sha256 = "@panther2-usb-panther2.ext4";
```

Where `panther2-usb-panther2.ext4` is an artifact listed in `SWUPDATE_IMAGES` variable.

More details can be found in:

- [Swupdate manual](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/building-with-yocto.html)
- [Swupdate readme](https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate/blob/master/README)
- [SWupdate board example](https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate-boards)

Comment: The new syntax is `sha256 = "$swupdate_get_sha256(panther2-usb-panther2.ext4)";`